# Find difference between two numbers in hours

Tags: mysql

We have an application which stores times as HHMM with breaks in minutes - I need to be able to find the difference in hours between two entries using MySQL. For example:

```
Start End  Breaks
0445  0825 030
```

This should return 3.167 hours

I tried using:

```
SELECT (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,start,end)-breaks) AS Duration
FROM table
```

which would work normally but as they are not valid times this returns NULL for everything.

I then thought about converting the integer to a datestamp first but cannot figure out how to do this as there is no seperator in the current time to try something like explode on.

How can I find the difference between these two and then subtract the break value?

Comment: Please show examples of not valid times the requested solution should work for

Comment: This should work for any time between 0000 and 2359 where within each hour the valid entries are 0000 to 0059 then 0100 to 0159 and so on

Answer (score 0):

Don't use time functions when not manipulating times (even if it looks like time).

A simple math will do the trick. Convert values to decimal representation in minutes (if you used decimal type: `T % 60 + 60 * FLOOR(T / 100)`) and then simply subtract the values as you need (`(a - b) / 60.`).